# What are the options in open source world for application lifecycle, fault and performance monitoring for .Net applications?

Tags: monitoring, application-lifecycle, performance

What are my options in open source world for application lifecycle, fault and performance monitoring for .Net applications? A good commercial benchmark for my need is Avicode (http://www.avicode.com)

So, is there an equivalent for Avicode?

Answer (score 1):

Not an equivalent...  however Microsoft recently acquired AVIcode.
More information along with a trial version is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/avicode.aspx)

http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/en/us/avicode.aspx

Thanks,
Aaron

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at dynatrace.
http://www.dynatrace.com/en/